# How to include different versions of same static library in an application?

Tags: linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I have an application which includes AA.so. AA.so internally includes CC.a version 1.

Now I have to include BB.so to the same application for some other feature. BB.so also includes CC.a version 2.

I don't have source code of any of these libraries.

My question is -
How to make sure that function calls from AA.so go to CC.a version 1 and calls from BB.so go to CC.a version 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to make sure that function calls from AA.so go to CC.a version 1 and calls from BB.so go to CC.a version 2?

You can't: making sure involves building `AA.so` and `BB.so` in a self-contained manner, and you can't rebuild them.

What you can do is *try* to make this work by loading the libraries at runtime using `dlopen("AA.so", RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_LOCAL)` and same for `BB.so`, and *hope* that the libraries don't step on each other.

In theory that (`RTLD_LOCAL` is the important bit) should work. In practice, there are many ways this could still break; you are venturing into very dangerous ground.

It could also work today, but break when either shared library is updated. You *really* should work with your library suppliers to get out of this multiple incompatible version mess.

**Update:**

> I believe shared objects do not depend on anything else and in that sense they are self-contained.

The "not depend on anything else" part is necessary, but not sufficient.

Normally, a shared library *exports* all global functions and data linked into it. Suppose `CC.a` contains a global function `foo`; suppose that versions 1 and 2 of this function are not compatible, and that `foo` is *exported* from both `AA.so` and `BB.so`. In that case, whichever library is loaded first will win. If `AA.so` is loaded first, then a call from `BB.so` to `foo` will get resolved to the definition inside `AA.so`, and your program will either corrupt its state, or crash.

To verify that this is not the case, you should run `nm -D` on `AA.so` and `BB.so`, and confirm that the intersection of symbols exported from these libraries is empty. If it is not empty, you have to verify that the two definitions are compatible.

Comment: Thank you @Employed Russian! But I believe shared objects do not depend on anything else and in that sense they are self-contained. So ideally, without any extra steps, AA.so should use CC.a version 1 and BB.so should use CC.a version 2 right?